# How to read only a specific part from HTTP Response body

Tags: c#, httpresponse, httpcontext, seek

I need to read only the `mode` segment from the below response body.

> grant_type=password&username=demouser&password=test123&client_id=500DWCSFS-D3C0-4135-A188-17894BABBCCF&mode=device

I used the below function to read the HTTP body and it gives me the entire body. How to chop the `mode` segment without using substring or changing the value in seek() : `bodyStream.BaseStream.Seek(3, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

```
var bodyStream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
bodyStream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var bodyText = bodyStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Did you try the bodyStream.ReadBlock() method?

Comment: @SimonH.No, Ill try it, Thanks

Comment: What reasoning is behind "without using substring" ?

Comment: @SimonH. ReadBlock() also requests parameter to specify a start index.  wont be able to specify an index because index might change based on the length of the username and password

Comment: @Fildor, Please refer the upper comment. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. HTTP uses TCP, which requires you to read the entire body anyway, you can't "seek" into a TCP stream. Well, you can, but that still reads the entire body and discards the unused pieces.

So you *have* to read the entire stream, and you *have* to meaningfully parse it, because another parameter could also contain the string "mode", and it could also be at the start, so you also can't search for `&mode`.

Given this is a form post, you can simply access `Request.Form["mode"]`. If you do want to parse it yourself:

```
string formData;
using (reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
{
    formData = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(formData);
var mode = queryString["mode"];
```

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster. This is what I want. +1